# After a 18 month J1 visa, can I come back to the US with ESTA and stay 3 months?

Tags: visas, esta, j1-visas

I'm from Italy and I had a J1 visa for the US for 18 months. Now it's expired (I'm in the grace period) so I'll soon go back to Italy. Since my boyfriend is American and lives in the US I would like to come back in January with the ESTA to visit him and probably stay 3 months and then return to Italy again.

According to my visa and DS-2019 form I'm not subject to the two years rule. Will I have any problem when entering the US with my ESTA? Should I wait longer before coming back? Do you think the immigration officer will make any problem since I have been in the US for so long (18 months) with the J1 visa?

Comment: Note that even if your J1 had a 2-year home residency requirement, that would not be relevant anyway as that only prevents you from getting H or L work visas or permanent residency.